# Never managed to keep a plant alive for more than a month and then I moved

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, english-ivy, snake-plants

So when I moved I got a lot of plants as housewarming gifts. So far so good, it has been 6 months and most of them are alive (except for the orchids). But now they are turning yellow and I don't think that's a good sign. I will post the pics.

For the Ivy I just removed them from their old pots and placed them in bigger pots with soil and for the Bogenhenf I repotted them as well. Could this have caused them to start yellowing?

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Hedera Helix] | [image: Sansevieria] |

Comment: what soil did you use when you potted them on? was it new, proper potting soil from a bag?

Comment: New potting soil. It said "universal potting soil "on the bag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soil in the pots looks as if its pretty wet, is it? It may be you're overwatering. The trick to watering is ito wait till the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry its shrunk from the sides of the pot. Water well and empty out any outer container or tray after 30 minutes, don't leave water sitting there.

The Bogenhenf (Sansevieria) is fortunately putting out new growth, so cut off the sickly leaves at their bases. This might have been caused by over watering, or just being kept in a place it doesn't like much, you haven't said anything about the conditions your plants are placed in.

The Ivy is showing signs of either yellowing or browning on one leaf edge in the picture, but otherwise looks healthy; again, over watering could be an issue, but also strong sunlight - ivies prefer bright light or dappled sunlight unless they're growing outdoors.

UPDATE

Following your comment, if a plant's soil is too wet, 4 days isn't long enough for it to dry out. Second, yes, it was a bad idea to move the plants into sunlight outdoors. Plants need acclimatizing to new conditions; they've been growing indoors for some time, with indoor temperatures, no wind, and not in direct sunlight for hours (presumably), so they're shocked when moved outdoors, particularly into direct sun, which may damage the leaves. A hardening off process is necessary prior to moving a plant outdoors whether that's permanently or just during summer.

Comment: Ah but I haven't watered it for 4 days and placed them all outside in direct Sun. Was that a bad idea?

Comment: Absolutely a bad idea - I'll update my answer

Comment: Ok just took all of them indoors. To harden them off I have to put them a couple of hours a day outdoors?

Comment: Yea - for extending periods over a week or two until they're outdoors all night (on a mild night). But don't leave them in sun - an hour or two early or late in the day is okay, otherwise, dappled sun or none at all. The ivy may be hardy over winter in  your area (not sure where you are) but unless you live somewhere warm, the Sansevieria won't be, it will need to be brought back indoors.